# Curly avocado leaves

Tags: indoors, avocado

Morning, everybody! I was hoping you could help me with my little avocado plant. Its' leaves started to curl up. I thought it was from overwatering, but now I only water it once a week and it still looks like this. Any ideas?
[image: avocado]

Comment: I have many avocado plants, the bigger ones dont do this while the smaller ones do. I don't know the answer either, but try reducing the watering. Also know that if an avocado plant becomes thirsty it's leaves will sag.

Comment: "The leaves will sag"...meaning like he is now? https://i.imgur.com/Ul1jkVV.jpg      I reduced the watering but I am afraid of not reducing it too much.

Comment: No, meaning they will go down and towards the stem.